# C# versus Java?

Tags: c#, java, programming-languages

So I'm a decent C# programmer and I love this language but ever since my only PC died on me all I have left is my Mac Book Pro and my dads PC which he uses for work.

He allows me use it but since he needs it for work the times I can works on my projects are significantly cut down. So im considering learning Java since its almost the same as C# but is cross platform...

Does Java have an IDE that has a winforms alternative (drag-n-drop GUI builder)?

Should I just suck it up and stick with C# since its a supirior language?

Does Java have the ability to program on something cool like how C# has XNA for xbox?

What looks better on a resume?

Ultimately what is a superior language?

-Thanks all!

Comment: .Net can run on Linux using Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: For superiousness, the issue has been discussed before.  I would suggest playing with the search box in the upper right corner of every page.

Comment: lol @ "superiousness"... let me guess, you're on the JAVA side of the fence?

Comment: @STW, I like both.  Unfortunately only Java runs on the platform my employer pays me to create code for.

Comment: There's plenty of C# jobs out there.  If you are already skilled in C# then owning a mac is no reason to jump to Java.  I program on my Mac in C# .net 3.5 using visual studio and windows.  Setup <a href="http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/">Boot camp</a>

Comment: My god, how does this question get asked so often?

Answer (score 4):

> What looks better on a resume?

Depends on what your potential employer is hiring for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd checkout MonoDevelop on OS X and [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) -- C# + .NET (read Mono) but on Linux and OS X... ;)

I know that doesn't directly answer your question, but it answeres the implied question based on the extra background you gave.

Comment: I've used it before. Its alright, not my favorite to use though...

Comment: IMHO, its better than any of the Java tools available for building GUIs.

Comment: I keep a notebook full of things I want to code eventually and its pretty full. So I guess I'll just stick with C# and .Net for a while..then I want to learn C++!

Answer (score 1):

On your Mac Book Pro you can install VirtualBox and install Windows in that.  You can then code .NET all you want...

Java is really nice for server side things.  Doing Java GUIs are notoriously difficult to write GUI's for.  The one in NetBeans is nice.

Comment: How similar is Java to C#, Can I just jump in or do I need to learn a a bit?

Comment: What's the difference between jumping in and learning a bit? You can't learn to swim without getting wet.

Comment: The languages are almost similar. The runtime libraries are quite different, but I guess you could pick it up rather quickly.